# Fail to install R packages

Tags: r, installation, package

```
> install.packages("rmarkdown")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘fastmap’, ‘glue’, ‘magrittr’, ‘stringi’, ‘knitr’, ‘yaml’, ‘htmltools’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘tinytex’, ‘xfun’, ‘jquerylib’, ‘stringr’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/rlang_0.4.12.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1200955 bytes (1.1 MB)
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/fastmap_1.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 215493 bytes (210 KB)
downloaded 210 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/glue_1.4.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 155685 bytes (152 KB)
downloaded 152 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/magrittr_2.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 235887 bytes (230 KB)
downloaded 230 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/stringi_1.7.5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 16449351 bytes (15.7 MB)
downloaded 15.7 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/knitr_1.36.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1469810 bytes (1.4 MB)
downloaded 1.4 MB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/yaml_2.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 207878 bytes (203 KB)
downloaded 203 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/htmltools_0.5.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 347479 bytes (339 KB)
downloaded 339 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/jsonlite_1.7.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 544517 bytes (531 KB)
downloaded 531 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/tinytex_0.34.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 123943 bytes (121 KB)
downloaded 121 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/xfun_0.27.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 381203 bytes (372 KB)
downloaded 372 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/jquerylib_0.1.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 525858 bytes (513 KB)
downloaded 513 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/stringr_1.4.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 216647 bytes (211 KB)
downloaded 211 KB

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/rmarkdown_2.11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3660952 bytes (3.5 MB)
downloaded 3.5 MB

Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Users/Admin/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/file23707312823/rlang/help/figures/rlang.png': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need to install `Rtools` before installing the `rmarkdown` package. You can do that from the following link: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/